# Prove that $\|a-2b+c\|^2 = 2\|a-b\|^2 + 2\|b-c\|^2 - \|a-c\|^2$

Tags: calculus, geometry, algebra-precalculus, euclidean-geometry, vector-analysis

How to show/prove that the following holds (i.e. in the simplest/fastest way using mathematical rules where possible):

$\|a-2b+c\|^2 = 2\|a-b\|^2 + 2\|b-c\|^2 - \|a-c\|^2$,

where $\|.\|$ denote the norm and $a,b,c$ are vectors in Euclidean space.

This is what I have so far:

$\|a-2b+c\|^2$ = $\|(a-b) + (c-b)\|^2 $ = $\|(a-b) + (c-b)\|^2 $ =  $\|a-b\|^2 + \|c-b\|^2 $ + $2\|a-b\|\cdot\|c-b\|$.

However, I don't know a simple mathematical way to show that:

$2\|a-b\|\cdot\|c-b\| = \|a-b\|^2 + \|c-b\|^2 - \|a-c\|^2$

Comment: The step $\|(a-b)+(c-b)\|^2 = \|a-b\|^2+\|c-b\|^2+2\|a-b\|\|c-b\|$ is not correct. That holds iff $\|(a-b)+(c-b)\|=\|a-b\|+\|c-b\|$, which isn't always true.

Comment: [As mentioned before,](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4783637/prove-that-a-2bc-2-2-a-b-2-2-b-c-2-a-c-2?noredirect=1#comment10168208_4783637) this is the parallelogram law.  Perhaps you recognize it better in the form $\|a-2b+c\|^2 + \|a-c\|^2= 2\|a-b\|^2 + 2\|b-c\|^2 $.

Comment: @MartinR The link does not work for me.

Comment: @user114263: Yes, Math98 had asked the same question today, and then deleted it. Only users with 10K reputation (and the author of the question) can see deleted questions. I had left a comment at the previous question that this is https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallelogram_law .

Comment: One can use scalar product, with $||v||^2=v\cdot v$

Comment: @MartinR thank you, does this parallelogram law have any conditions? At the link you have sent, in the section 'The parallelogram law in inner product spaces' I think it holds in general. However, user114263 says it holds for specific cases.  Moreover, it indeed proves my relation instantly, so that's very nice.

Answer (score 2):

Set $x=a-b$ and $y=b-c$. Then $x+y=a-c$ and $x-y=a-2b+c$. And we need to show:
$$
\|x-y\|^2+\|x+y\|^2=2(\|x\|^2+\|y\|^2)\ .
$$
This is a polarization formula, the parallelogram law.
It always holds, when the norm comes from a scalar product, so
$\|x\|^2=\langle x,x\rangle$, with the proof:
$$
\begin{aligned}
\|x-y\|^2&=\langle x-y,x-y\rangle 
=\langle x,x\rangle -2\langle x,y\rangle + \langle y,y\rangle\ ,\\
\|x+y\|^2&=\langle x+y,x+y\rangle 
=\langle x,x\rangle +2\langle x,y\rangle + \langle y,y\rangle\ ,\\
\|x-y\|^2 + \|x+y\|^2&=2\langle x,x\rangle + 2\langle y,y\rangle
=2(\|x\|^2+\|y\|^2)\ .
\end{aligned}
$$
In school the proof is given in the context of a parallelogram with sides, vectors, $x$ and $y$, both having the same origin, the origin of the plane.
Then the diagonals are the vectors $x\pm y$. Now apply the generalized Pythagoras theorem for the two triangles with sides built on the one or the other diagonal, and for each diagonal take two of the sides of the parallelogram to build a triangle. The two triangles have - opposite to the diagonals - two supplemantary angles - so the cosines from the two Pythagoras have different signs, and the corresponding terms cancel each other when we sum the squared lengths of the diagonals.